# Eight queens print nothing in recursion in C

Tags: c, n-queens

I am having a C course myself. When I run my code, nothing happened(print nothing), and I can't find out the problem.
And I found my check function clumsy, how can i improve it, make it slim and simple?
Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ON     1
#define OFF    0
#define SIZE   8

void initial(int (*table)[SIZE]);
void setqueen(int (*table)[SIZE], const int row);
int check(const int (*table)[SIZE], const int row, const int col);
void prtable(const int (*table)[SIZE]);

int main(void)
{
        int table[SIZE][SIZE];
        int row = 0;

        initial(table);

        setqueen(table, row);

        return 0;
}

void initial(int (*table)[SIZE])
{
        int row, col;

        for (row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
                for (col = 0; col < SIZE; col++)
                        table[row][col] = OFF;
}
/*
place a queen(set value = 1) in the first column of the first row and
check there is no conflict. if there is a conflict, count and move to
next column. if there is conflict in every column(count = 8), return.
if there is no conflict, call it recursively. when it place all queens,
print the table.
*/
void setqueen(int (*table)[SIZE], const int row)
{
        int c = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for ( ; c < SIZE; c++) {
                table[row][c] = ON;
                if (check(table, row, c) == ON) {
                        table[row][c] = OFF;
                        count++;
                        continue;
                }
                if (count == SIZE)
                        return;
                if (row != SIZE - 1)
                        setqueen(table, row + 1);
                else
                        prtable(table);
        }
}

void prtable(const int (*table)[SIZE])
{
        int row, col;

        for (row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
                for (col = 0; col < SIZE; col++)
                        printf("%2d", table[row][col]);
                putchar('\n');
        }
        putchar('\n');
}

int check(const int (*table)[SIZE], const int row, const int col)
{
        int r = 0;
        int c = 0;

        for (r = 0; r < SIZE; r++)
                if (r != row && table[r][col] == ON)
                        return ON;
        for (c = 0; c < SIZE; c++)
                if (c != col && table[row][c] == ON)
                        return ON;
        for (r = row + 1, c = col + 1;
             (r >= 0 && r < SIZE) || (c >= 0 && c < SIZE);
             r++, c++)
                if (table[r][c] == ON)
                        return ON;
        for (r = row + 1, c = col - 1;
             (r >= 0 && r < SIZE) || (c >= 0 && c < SIZE);
             r++, c--)
                if (table[r][c] == ON)
                        return ON;
        for (r = row - 1, c = col + 1;
             (r >= 0 && r < SIZE) || (c >= 0 && c < SIZE);
             r--, c++)
                if (table[r][c] == ON)
                        return ON;
        for (r = row - 1, c = col - 1;
             (r >= 0 && r < SIZE) || (c >= 0 && c < SIZE);
             r--, c--)
                if (table[r][c] == ON)
                        return ON;

        return OFF;
}
```

Comment: `I can't find out the problem.` What all did you try?

Comment: have you verified your `prtable` function called or not?

Comment: What did you find out while debugging?

Comment: I'm still a newbie, and i haven't learn how to use debug tools like gdb, so 'I can't find the problem', i mean, i can't find out the problem logically.

Comment: I am not sure if you can use `table[SIZE][SIZE];` without allocating memory !! [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/?kw=malloc)

Comment: `static int count = 0` in function setqueen

Comment: To Ayush, nothing happened too...

Comment: In which line are you backtracking?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Now would be a perfect time to try using gdb or other tools. Even if you don't do that, you could use the time-honoured method of adding printfs to understand what is happening better before asking for help.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i have used printf to correct problems before i ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't recurse as you expect.
`setqueen` calls `setqueen` which tries all possibilities, but if that fail it then just tries to place queens on the same row in the `for(c)` loop, which will fail.
Call `prtable` at the beginning of `setqueen` to see what the algorithm is doing, you'll see:

```
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Then the algorithm will try to place a queen on the row 5, fail but does not try to move previously placed queens.
`setqueen` should also remove the queen `table[row][c] = OFF;` and move to next when the recursive call to `setqueen` fails (so it should return a value).

Apart from that, it looks to me that `count` and `c` are the same thing, you could initialize c in the for loop rather than before (more readable), add comments in the check on what each for loop checks (column, line, ...), and avoid to use ON and OFF for check return value (not clear what that means).

Answer (score -1):

In function `void setqueen(int (*table)[SIZE], const int row)` you should do `static int count=0` because every time the function is called recursively count is set to 0 even if there are queens placed on board.

See the below code for assistance

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 8
#define true 1
#define false 0
void printsol(int sol[][N])
{
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",sol[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
int issafe(int sol[][N],int x,int y)
{
int i,j;

//Check Row
for(i=x,j=y-1;j>=0;j--)
{
    if(sol[i][j]==1)
        return false;
}

//Check Upper left diagonal
for(i=x-1,j=y-1;i>=0 && j>=0;i--,j--)
{
    if(sol[i][j]==1)
        return false;
}

//Check Lower Left Diagonal
for(i=x+1,j=y-1;i<N && j>=0;i++,j--)
{
    if(sol[i][j]==1)
        return false;
}

return true;
}
int solve(int sol[][N],int x,int y)
{
int i,j=y;
if(y==N)
{
    printsol(sol);
    return 1;
}
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    //printf("LOL");
    if(issafe(sol,i,y)==true)
    {

        sol[i][y]=1;
        if(solve(sol,0,y+1)==true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            sol[i][y]=0;
    }
}
return false;
}
int main()
{
int sol[N][N];
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        sol[i][j]=0;

solve(sol,0,0);
}
```

Comment: - Did you try ragonci's code with your proposed fix ?